# Individual zoom on two separate D3 tree in one browser window but different svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, zooming

I have two svg panels added in one HTML , both are displaying separate trees.
I want to add individual zoom behaviour on both the panels.

Currently the zoom function works on only one of the panel

Zoom funciton 1

```

```
var zoom = function() {
    var scale = d3.event.scale,
        translation = d3.event.translate,
        tbound = -height * scale,
        bbound = height * scale,
        lbound = (-width + margin.right) * scale,
        rbound = (width - margin.left) * scale;
    // limit translation to thresholds
    translation = [
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
    ];
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

```

Zoom funciton 2
```

```
var zoom2 = function() {
    var scale2 = d3.event.scale,
        translation2 = d3.event.translate,
        tbound2 = -height2 * scale2,
        bbound2 = height2 * scale2,
        lbound2 = (-width2 + margin2.right) * scale2,
        rbound2 = (width2 - margin2.left) * scale2;
    // limit translation to thresholds
    translation2 = [
        Math.max(Math.min(translation2[0], rbound2), lbound2),
        Math.max(Math.min(translation2[1], bbound2), tbound2)
    ];
    svg2.attr("transform", "translate(" + translation2 + ")" + " scale(" + scale2 + ")");
}
```

`I am creating two of such functions and calling them with each of the tree`

```
d3.select("svg")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
        .on("zoom", zoom));
```

```
d3.select("svg")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
        .on("zoom", zoom2));
```

```
But only the function which is define in the ends is working .

How to add separate zoom for both the trees.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed ,

The solution was to use id while getting svg.
```

```
d3.select("#Chart svg")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
        .on("zoom", zoom2));
```

```